# Save as pdf using a Mac

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word, file-conversion, export-to-pdf

I have to adapt some macros for use on Macs.

The following code runs on Windows but the pdf isn't created on Mac machines.

```vb
Sub ExportAndSave()

    ActiveDocument.Save

    Dim currentfolder As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim mypath As String

    'Store Information About Word File
    mypath = ActiveDocument.FullName
    currentfolder = ActiveDocument.Path & "\"
    filename = Mid(mypath, InStrRev(mypath, "\") + 1, _
      InStrRev(mypath, ".") - InStrRev(mypath, "\") - 1)

    'Export PDF as [filename]-edit
   
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 filename:=currentfolder & filename & "-edit", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
     
    'Accept changes and save as [filename]-edit

    ActiveDocument.Revisions.AcceptAll
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 filename:=currentfolder & filename & "-edit"
    
End Sub
```

I altered the syntax for the file location so no errors crop up, and sorted out permissions to not get popups asking to grant access. It's running smoothly with no error messages.

Comment: In your code `filename` seems to be missing the required `.pdf` file extension.

Comment: Is the [Document.ExportAsFixedFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat) method available on the Mac OS?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev - unfortunately not!

Comment: What is the exact result string passed to the `SaveAs2` method?

Answer (score 0):

AFAICS your code has two problems:

On Mac I think you will need to change the backslash characters to forward slashes, i.e.

```
currentfolder = ActiveDocument.Path & "/"
 filename = Mid(mypath, InStrRev(mypath, "/") + 1, _
 InStrRev(mypath, ".") - InStrRev(mypath, "/") - 1)
```

Then, (as @TimothyRylatt mentions), you have not provided an extension. But the problem is that *neither* of the two `.SaveAs2` calls provides one, so the docx version in the second call will overwrite the pdf in the first call. Lack of any extension also makes it difficult for Mac to choose suitable applications to open the file (just as on Windows). Just be aware that Mac may not *display* the extensions in Finder.

(Incidentally, in theory, forward slashes *may* also work on Windows despite the widespread perception that it only allows backslash, but I leave you to check that. You can also use Application.PathSeparator to give you the correct separator, as long as your code does not have to work on much older versions of Word/Mac that have to use the older colon-separated pathnames, because the path naming convention has other differences in that case).

Comment: Thank you! Strangely I already changed the backslashes to forward slashes, I must have accidentally pasted an older version. I see what you mean in terms of adding a file extension - would you just add it by changing it to filename & "-edit.pdf" ? Perhaps that's a super basic question, I just want to make sure I've understood!

Comment: @Billy, yes re "-edit.pdf" and add .docx or whatever to the other one.